# kubectl: error You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)

Tags: kubernetes

I've created a service account for CI purposes and am testing it out. Upon trying any kubectl command, I get the error:

```
error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)
```

Below is my `.kube/config` file

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    server: <redacted>
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: bamboo
  name: default
current-context: 'default'
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: bamboo
  user:
    token: <redacted>
```

The service account exists and has a cluster role: edit and cluster role binding attached.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: May I know where is your cluster running On Prem or Cloud? If 'Cloud' Which one please?

Comment: @hariK it is on prem

Comment: did you decode token before using? @bear

Comment: I was missing that apparently @hoque

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I reproduce the error if I copy the `token` directly without decoding. Then applied  the following steps to decode and set the token and it is working as expected.

```
$ TOKENNAME=`kubectl -n <namespace> get serviceaccount/<serviceaccount-name> -o jsonpath='{.secrets[0].name}'` 

$ TOKEN=`kubectl -n <namespace> get secret $TOKENNAME -o jsonpath='{.data.token}'| base64 --decode`

$ kubectl config set-credentials <service-account-name> --token=$TOKEN
```

So, I think it might be your case.